# Windows 7 magnifier not fullscreen

Tags: windows-7, windows, magnifier

I don't have the option to set the Windows 7 magnifier full-screen (it's gray), it is docked on top of the screen, and that's it can't change it.

Anybody know how to fix this ?

Answer (score 6):

1. Close the Magnifier
2. Go into the registry (Start -> Run -> type in regedit and then click OK).
3. Navigate to the following key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\ScreenMagnifier`
4. Under the MagnificationMode DWORD value, change that to either 2 or 3.
5. Close Registry Editor
6. Now go to the Services snap-in (Start -> Run -> type in services.msc ) and then click OK.
7. Scroll to the "Desktop Window Manager Session" service.  Right-click on it, and then left-click "Restart."
8. Close the Services snap-in.
9. Open up the Magnifier again.  If you changed the DWORD to 2, then it'll be in Full Screen mode.  If you changed it to 3, then it'll be in Lens mode.

Comment: I only have `MagnifierUIWindowMinimized` and `RunBefore` on `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\ScreenMagnifier
`. Do I have to create a new `MagnificationMode` DWORD value?

Answer (score 4):

you have aero disabled. try to select the aero theme and test again. Also if the service isn't running execute in a console "net start uxsms" as administrator. If that doesn't work maybe some program that is executing disable aero for incompatibilities. For example quicktime is going to disable aero. If that is the case remove that unnecesary apps. If that isn't the case then maybe your graphic adapter is incapable of running aero. The only solution to that is change the adapter.

Comment: this helped me and avoided the hassle to mess around with my registry

Answer (score 1):

I had Aero turned on, but I needed to change my display settings to 32-bit color on both monitors before the magnifier became available.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! This site is not a forum, and we are happy to accept answers no matter how long it has been since the question was asked.

Answer (score 0):

Try dragging the Magnifier window down towards the middle of the desktop.

Or try switching to another Magnifier mode: `Ctrl+Alt+F` for full screen, `Ctrl+Alt+L` for Lens.

Comment: doesn't help, also I'm with windows classic theme (if that matters)

Comment: doesn't help. https://superuser.com/questions/1506728/full-screen-and-lens-mode-in-magnifier-windows-7-enterprise-grayed-out

Answer (score 0):

You have disabled aero theme. Right click on desktop > personalize > Scroll down to find aero theme > click on either one.

Comment: How does aero affect the full screen magnifier?

Comment: @Simon Sheehan I'm thinking the same...

Comment: Nope ... doesn't work

https://superuser.com/questions/1506728/full-screen-and-lens-mode-in-magnifier-windows-7-enterprise-grayed-out

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you do not have anything that inhibiting Aero effects. Try to use Aero by holding <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. If you do not get the Aero effect than there maybe a mirror driver that is causing Aero to be disabled even if you have it set in Personalization.

There are several programs that disables Aero Theme effects. You can troubleshoot Aero in the Personalization screen. Near the bottom is a blue link that says something like "troubleshoot AERO theme effects".

My problem was I had mirror drivers enabled from JAWS. A screen reading program.

Comment: I'm on windows 10, and it works